# comparing two numerical variables in R

Tags: r

I have run the R function stl() function and use its generated residuals for grubbs test. The code is the following:

```
stl.res = stl(dataset, s.windows='periodic')
residuals = as.numeric(strl.res$time.series[, "remainder"])
grubbs.result = grubbs.test(residuals)

strsplit(grubbs.result$alternative," ")[[1]][3]
## [1] "38.4000349179783"

outlier = as.numeric(strsplit(grubbs.result$alternative," ")[[1]][3])
outlier
## [1] 38.40003492

which(residuals == outlier)
## integer(0)
```

My question is why the return value of `which()` is 0. Actually `residuals[1920] = 38.4000349179783`. So the call of `which()` should return a value of 1921, not 0. I guess this is a problem with precision. I have tried many ways, but not managed to solve it.

Comment: what about something like `which(abs(residuals - outlier) < 1e-9)`?

Answer (score 0):

If it's really a precision issue (which would be R FAQ 7.31), then there are various ways to get around it.

```
# this is an approximation of your test
x <- c(1, 2, 38.4000349179783, 4, 5)
y <- 38.40003492

> x == y
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# so which doesn't return anything


# one basic approach

> which(abs(x - y) < .00001)
[1] 3
```

You could also rig up something using all.equal(), but checking for a difference less than your pre-selected limit is probably easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `isTrue()` and `all.equal()` as below:

```
which(sapply(residuals, function(v) isTrue(all.equal(v,outlier))) == T)
```